# Unexpected token J in JSON at position 2 with iTunes url

Tags: angular, getjson, angular2-observables

I am trying to run through the Angular tutorial on Observables by codecraft (here: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/)
but I keep getting this error reported on my Chrome browser, as soon as I enter the any character.

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token J in JSON at position 2
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json (http.es5.js:797)
    at MapSubscriber.<anonymous> (itunes.service.ts:21)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
```

and so on.  It looks like the problem is in this piece of code:

```
  let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?term=${term}&media=music&limit=20&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
  return this.http.get(apiURL) 
      .map(res => {
        return res.json().results.map(item => { // This seems to be the problem line 21
          return new SearchItem( 
              item.trackName,
              item.artistName,
              item.trackViewUrl,
              item.artworkUrl30,
              item.artistId
          );
        });
      });
```

So is this a mistake in the tutorial or has something changed at the URL requested or has something changed in Angular (I'm using 4.3.1). I'm editing with the Angular IDE and it shows no errors in the code.  Most of the other responses to questions like this point to the returned object not being in json format.  I'm afraid I'm not that well informed on the vagaries of HTML transfers or json debugging to find any further information.

Comment: Well first of all you can check your network tab and see how your response looks like. Your assumption is correct, it is not valid JSON that you are getting.

Comment: Responses can come in all different sorts. You can put in a breakpoint and see what your response is. You might need `res.json()` only, or something more complicated like `res.json().value.results`. You'll need to code your service to match what you are getting.

Comment: Embarrassingly the problem was very simple to fix in the end.  The final part of the url string I used (JSONP_CALLBACK) was being appended to the response string returned from the site.  Removing that end part resulted in the correct response string which was pure json format.

Comment: In other words the response started JSONP_CALLBACK instead of {. I think that url was meant to be used in a later part of the tutorial that was using jsonP formatting.